# Why does a "cavity with a hole" model of a black body not absorb/emit radiation larger than the size of the hole/cavity?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

[This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#Cavity_with_a_hole) on the "cavity with a hole" model of a black body says:

> The hole is not quite a perfect black surface — in particular, if the wavelength of the incident radiation is longer than the diameter of the hole, part will be reflected. Similarly, even in perfect thermal equilibrium, the radiation inside a finite-sized cavity will not have an ideal Planck spectrum for wavelengths comparable to or larger than the size of the cavity.

So I have 2 questions.:

Why is it that light of a wavelength larger than the hole will be reflected?

Why are wavelengths larger than the size of the cavity not emitted?

Answer (score 1):

The propagation of an EM wave through a small hole decays very quickly, like $d^4$, so while it can propagate it's very unlikely. Same principle that makes the microwave mesh a good way for us not to be microwaved too.

Related question: [Why are electromagnetic waves not able to pass through a hole with a diameter smaller than the wavelength?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155221/why-are-electromagnetic-waves-not-able-to-pass-through-a-hole-with-a-diameter-sm)